# How to speed up loading of Google Analytics 4 tracker?

Tags: google-analytics, google-tag-manager

I’ve been experiencing a discrepancy in terms of page views between GA4 and GA3, both installed through GTM page view event.

I notice that GA4 is much slower to send the collect request compared to GA3, literally takes 3-4 seconds more from my office connection and pc.
I think that this is the main cause of discrepancy between the two.

Is it possible to somehow speed up GA4 tracker?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I remembered Google design this feature.

Here is the reference from a blog post

> One thing you might have noticed is the delay it takes for the hit to
> be sent. When you load the page, you can see how the browser waits a
> few seconds before dispatching the hit to GA. This is because GAv2
> batches requests automatically, which, again, is a great feature
> upgrade.

[Link](https://www.simoahava.com/analytics/getting-started-with-google-analytics-app-web/)

---

GA4 now will send multiple event as one request. But you don't need to worry about this will lost some event if user close the browser suddenly.

Here is the article from Google

> Note: When a user's device goes offline (for example, a user loses their internet connection while browsing your mobile app), Google Analytics stores event data on their device and then sends the data once their device is back online. Analytics ignores events that arrive more than 72 hours after the events are triggered.

[Link](https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/9322688?hl=en)

Comment: Thanks for your answer. The fact is, I cannot see this behaviour happening in this site. If I switch pages before the batch is sent, I see no network request for GA4.

Comment: I think the possible reason is the GA4 code is not even loading in your first page. Can you check the GTM is loading on your first page and the GA4 tag is fired?